# Package wont extract: stolinski

Tags: meteor, package

Can someone please assist me ?

I've tried adding the following package:

```
stolinski:stylus-multi
```

I desperately need to get this working but for some reason it just hangs on 
`Extracting stolinski:stylus-multi@1.4... /`

I even left it over night to run.
I'm using the latest version of meteor
Please any help would appreciated.

Comment: same case with me ... whats up with this package

Comment: @Jacques Did you ever resolve this? I'm running on Windows and experiencing it as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by using the package mquandalle:stylus instead of stolinski:stylus-multi